# Redirect 410 url pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i like to ask some help for proper redirect 410 after site migration

my previous cms creating pattern similar like this

```
https://www.website.com/search/label/books?updated-max=2019-10-19T07:06:00-07:00max-results%3D20start=20by-date=falsem=0
https://www.website.com/search/label/magazine?updated-max=2019-10-19T07:06:00-07:00max-results%3D20start=20by-date=falsem=0
```

what i want to achieve is to set everything after `label` to point at 410 status in my htaccess, but `search` still intact 200 status (as wordpress also using it as search query)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try this simple rule in your .htaccess file. This will redirect any url whose uri contains `label` to 410 status. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before you test your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule label - [G]
```